Data visualization API - Modelstructureinfo #getRoomList returns empty array - "devices did not map to a room"
As you can see the in the following picture, my sprite is positioned at the center of the room. I'm using the same location for the device coordinates:

const structureInfo =
                    new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(
                      model
                    );

const devices = [
                    {
                      id: "lobby-01",
                      position: {
                        x: -160.19818878173828,
                        y: 23.581119537353516,
                        z: -4.738031387329102,
                      },
                      sensorTypes: [
                        "temperature",
                        "humidity",
                      ], 
                    },
                  ];

const shadingData =
                    await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(
                      devices
                    );
                  await dataVizExtn.setupSurfaceShading(
                    model,
                    shadingData
                  );
    const sensorColors = [
                    0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xffff00,
                    0xff0000,
                  ];
                  const sensorType =
                    "temperature";
                  dataVizExtn.registerSurfaceShadingColors(
                    sensorType,
                    sensorColors
                  );
                  const getSensorValue = (
                    surfaceShadingPoint,
                    sensorType
                  ) => {
                    // The `SurfaceShadingPoint.id` property matches one of the identifiers passed
                    // to `generateSurfaceShadingData` function. In our case above, this will either
                    // be "cafeteria-entrance-01" or "cafeteria-exit-01".
                    const deviceId =
                      surfaceShadingPoint.id;

                    // Read the sensor data, along with its possible value range
                    let sensorValue =
                      readSensorValue(
                        deviceId,
                        sensorType
                      );
                    const maxSensorValue =
                      getMaxSensorValue(
                        sensorType
                      );
                    const minSensorValue =
                      getMinSensorValue(
                        sensorType
                      );

                    // Normalize sensor value to [0, 1.0]
                    sensorValue =
                      (sensorValue -
                        minSensorValue) /
                      (maxSensorValue -
                        minSensorValue);

                    return clamp(
                      sensorValue,
                      0.0,
                      1.0
                    );
                  };

                  dataVizExtn.renderSurfaceShading(
                    "lobby-01",
                    sensorType,
                    getSensorValue
                  );

                  const rooms =
                    await structureInfo.getRoomList(
                      "Rooms"
                    );
                  console.log(shadingData, rooms);

However, none of the heatmaps are rendered and I still getting this message in the console:

I even checked that the nodeName for the rooms is the same as "Rooms" by using those commands:
NOP_VIEWER.model.getInstanceTree().getNodeParentId(19967);
NOP_VIEWER.model.getInstanceTree().getNodeName(19966,false);

I double checked that I was using the correct nodeName ("Rooms"). I also made sure the devices were placed inside the room geometry.
Lastly, I set a setTimeOut() callback so the heatmap code could be run some seconds after the documentNode had loaded within the Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load() method.
Finally, here is my heatmap gradient:

